# Web Application Servers Infrastructure and Configuration (to Display and Stream Media with laravel & Nginx)

Tags: laravel, nginx, ftp, http-live-streaming, infrastructure

I have questions about the infrastructure, and configuration of servers in a particular web application (to display and stream media). I am new to this field and my question may be simple. I would be grateful if you could guide me.

The web application I am considering is an **interactive website** where users upload their media such as **images, videos and audio**.
I have two servers, One of them has the web application (based on Laravel and MySQL) and User-uploaded files are stored on another server (by FTP).

- Server 1: **Web Application**
- Server 2: **FTP server for storing media**
- Server 3: **Database Server**

Now my questions include several sections:

- How to **display** files stored in FTP Server to users and how to **link (URL of Media)** to them within the laravel project.
- I know that we can **stream videos and audio** by making some configurations in **Nginx** (Based on this [Link](https://dev.to/samuyi/how-to-setup-nginx-for-hls-video-streaming-on-centos-7-3jb8)). Now in my scenario that the files are stored on another server, how should this be done (Especially with video.js)? Should all HTTP requests be sent to the web application server and a decision made based on the path? For example, redirecting requests.
- In which server should **Streaming or HLS settings** be made? Should Nginx be installed on both servers? Do I need a Reverse Proxy to do this?
- In general, is the infrastructure and scenario provided a **suitable solution**? Or is there a better infrastructure?
- In most of the references I saw, they have not considered the situation in which there are different servers. Is there a **reference** for such a situation that I should read?

Thank You